# Lua - Most resource efficient way to compare a variable to a fixed list of values

Tags: lua, lua-table

So I have a variable, let's call it 'ID'. I need to check this value relative to a fixed amount of values. The ID, of course, can only match one of the values so there isn't an issue with stopping on the first matching value as none of the others would match. There is also a chance that the variable does not match any of the given values, too. My question is then, what is the most resource efficient way to do this? I can think of two easy ways of tackling the problem. Since I know the values at the time of programming I can setup a conditional with 'or' that just checks each value, like so:

```
if (ID == "1" or ID == "16" or ID == "58") then
    --do something--
end
```

The problem with this is that it's quite verbose and tedious to write. The other option involves a foreach loop where I define a table beforehand.

```
values = {"1", "16", "58"}
for _, value in ipairs(values) do
    if(ID == value) then
        return true
    end
end
```

The upside to this is it's reusable which is good since I'll need to do this exact check with a different set of values at least 10 times, the downside is I suspect it takes more resources.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tables can be used as sets:

```
interesting = {
   ["1"] = true, ["16"] = true, ["58"] = true
}

if interesting[ID] then
   -- ...
end
```

While it eats more memory (80 bytes per empty table plus 32 bytes (IIRC, on x86_64) per entry (while rounding the number of entries up to the next power of two) vs. 16 bytes per comparison plus storage for the value that you compare) the chain of comparisons happens in C and is therefore faster than a chain of comparisons as a sequence of Lua instructions (at least once things get larger).

For small numbers of values, this doesn't really matter.  (If you are CPU-bound and this is very important in your case, measure *in the context of your program* and see what performs better.  Don't put too much weight on micro-benchmarks with this – cache behavior in particular might produce funny effects here.)

For large numbers of comparisons, this is the right approach.  It's also more flexible than `if`-`then`-`else` chains.  (You can change things at runtime without reloading code.)

Also note that the value you use to anchor an element in the set doesn't really matter, so a relatively common idiom (especially for input handling) is putting the action as a function into the table:

```
keybindings = {
   left = function()  Player:move_left( )  end,
   right = function()  Player:move_right( )  end,
   up = function()  Player:jump( )  end,
   -- ...
}

function onKey( k )
   local action = keybindings[k]
   if action then  action( )  end
end
```

While this certainly is slower than a direct comparison and inline code, speed is essentially irrelevant here (generally happens much less often than ~100x per second) and flexibility is of high value.